# How to properly handle sate changes in ReactJS with multiple dropdown elements for multiple charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

By now I know how to update only one chart when I select any value in one dropdown element. But I have no idea how to implement some code to do the same for multiple charts. What I want to render is a dashboard with multiple dropdowns and charts. Each dropdown value controls all charts in the tab at the same time.

What I tried is the following (sorry that I don't post my code, it's too large and it has several lines of code for other purposes):

1. I created a class (I'm not using Hooks) where I handle the state changes for everything: the charts and the dropdowns.
2. I created a *ComponentWillMount* to extract the data from my database. In this component, I update the datasets containing one chart data.
3. I created a *ComponentDidMount* in which I update the state of the dropdown elements (only one dropdown).
4. I created a *handleChange* function in which I update the chart values according to the selection set in the dropdown.
5. I finally render the dropdown and chart elements, where I call the *handleChange* function and the datasets.

Now, I don't know how to work with the other elements. I thought I could:

1. Update all my charts datasets in *ComponentWillMount*.
2. Update all my charts in *handleChange*.

However, I tried this for two charts and is not working (only one is updating). I'm not sure if I'm not using properly the components I mentioned. I tried looking for examples but some of them use only one dropdown, or they use React hooks.

In summary, I'm asking for help to structure my code so that I can handle correctly my components state changes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do - perhaps you could provide some code or an image of what you're trying to create... If multiple chart components rely on the same state value -  I would lift up state and pass it down as a prop to the child components. There are many ways to handle this problem, you could use context to store the shared state, or have a container component to handle the state logic...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.